# Ruby map and compact methods

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator

Given a number `n`, I would like to return its factorial (`1*2*3...*n`). but only the even numbers between `1` and `n`.

This is the working code that I have now.

```
def fact_even(n)
  arr = (1..n).map {|m| m if m % 2 == 0}
  new_arr = arr.compact
  new_arr.inject(&:*)
end
```

When given the block, `map` returns a new array:

```
[nil, 2, nil, 4, nil, 6]
```

I have to use the `compact` method afterwards to get rid of the `nil`s, and then use `inject` to get the answer to the factorial.

Is there a way to have `map` return an array with only the even numbers so I do not have to use `compact` in the next line? Otherwise, is there a more effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `select`

```
> (1..20).select { |r| r % 2 == 0}
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Also, you can try to use `reduce` for the next line:

```
> (1..20).select { |r| r % 2 == 0 }.reduce(:*)
=> 3715891200
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 2.7 added `Enumerable#filter_map`. If you are using a version greater or equals to 2.7 you can do:

```
(1..n).filter_map { |m| m if m.even? }
```

However, `select` would be a better option for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `even?` instead of `r % 2 == 0`

```
n = 20
(1..n).select { |r| r.even? }.reduce(:*)
# Output: => 3715891200
```

Notice that both `inject` and `reduce` point to the same method.

```
Range.instance_method(:inject) == Range.instance_method(:reduce)
# Output: => true
```